# Double hash entries while printing

Tags: perl

As part of a bigger program I've got a hash. I'm testing the program printing the keys but they are all duplicates, I don't know why

```
while ( my $line = <SEQ> ) {

  chomp $line;
  $line =~ s/>//;

  my ( @split1 ) = split( "\t", $line );

  foreach my $chr ( keys %position ) {

     #print Dumper \%position;
     print "$chr\n";

     foreach my $pos ( sort keys %{ $position{$chr} } ) {

        if ( $split1[0] =~ /$chr/ ) {
           #print "$chr\t$pos\n";
        }
     }
   }
}
```

`%position` is a nested hash, when I print the keys on `print "$chr\n";` they are all doubled and I don't understand why.

The file opened on handle `SEQ` looks like this:

```
>chr1\tACTGTAGTCTCATCCTAT...
>chr2\tACGTAGCTAGT....
```

and so on

Comment: What does the data that your are reading from the `SEQ` filehandle look like?

Comment: SEQ looks like this: >chr1\tACTGTAGTCTCATCCTAT...\n>chr2\tACGTAGCTAGT....\n and so on

Comment: Can you edit the file example into your question? It is difficult to read in the comment section.

Comment: You have a `foreach` inside a `while`, which will print all of the keys of the `%position` hash for every line of input. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It looks like here is an real need for a book: `Using perl for genetics`. Many similar questions about reading FASTA files. Please don't reinvent the wheel 10-th times. Search METACPAN for [FASTA](https://metacpan.org/search?size=500&q=fasta&search_type=modules), choose one of existing modules like [Bio::DB::Fasta](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::DB::Fasta) or [GenOO::Data::File::FASTA](https://metacpan.org/pod/GenOO::Data::File::FASTA), install and use it. Sure will get better result as with your code-segments.

Comment: @jm666: [There are several](http://amzn.to/2959dna). There's a real need for them to be *read*

Comment: @Borodin touché! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `foreach` loop inside a `while` which will print all of the keys of the `%position` hash for every line of input

That will cause symptoms like what you're describing. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
my %data;
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my ($chr, $seq) = split;
    $data{$chr} = $seq;
}

print Dumper \%data;
```

Comment: How can that possibly solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: @BlueStarry - Whose answer to what now?

Comment: @Borodin - This was intended as a helpful push in the right direction. As is it's impossible to discern what the OP is actually trying to do

Comment: @fugu: Then it belongs as a comment and not a solution